# How to calculate `mean` and `sd` of lognormal distribution based on `meanlog` and `sdlog`?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution

Lognormal distribution as below:

```
        estimate 
meanlog   6.0515   
sdlog     0.3703
```

How to calculate the `mean` and `sd` of this distribution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be lognormally distributed. Denote $\mu$ and $\sigma$ as the mean and standard deviation of $\log(X)$. The mean and standard deviation of $X$ are [given by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Arithmetic_moments):
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}(X)&=e^{\mu + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}} \\
\mathrm{SD}(X) &= e^{\mu + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}}\sqrt{e^{\sigma^{2}}-1}
\end{align}

In your case, that means:
\begin{align}
\hat{x} &= 454.89\\
\hat{\sigma} &= 174.39
\end{align}

Here is a custom R function that implements these formulas:

```
logno_moments <- function(meanlog, sdlog) {
  m <- exp(meanlog + (1/2)*sdlog^2)
  s <- exp(meanlog + (1/2)*sdlog^2)*sqrt(exp(sdlog^2) - 1)
  return(list(mean = m, sd = s))
}
```

It returns a list with the transformed mean and standard deviation:

```
meanlog <- 6.0515
sdlog <- 0.3703

logno_moments(meanlog, sdlog)

$mean
[1] 454.8925

$sd
[1] 174.3895
```

Comment: Is there any R function can be used?I cannot remember formula of each distribution?

Comment: `exp(6.0515+0.5*(0.3703^2))*sqrt(exp(0.3703^2)-1)=174.4`,different result?

Comment: @kittygirl Yes, the numbers were off, thanks. I have corrected the values and added a custom R function that does the calculations automatically.